# conditional split of a string

Tags: go, split

I want to split a string of type 'a/b/c' and allow escaping by '\'.
For example:

```
'foo/bar\/2.2/baz':
a=foo
b=bar/2.2
c=baz
```

Is there any elegant way to split by '/', ignoring '\/'?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Do you need to be able to escape \ as well, e.g. `"foo\\/bar"` would result in `["foo\","bar"]`?

Comment: @Flimzy I tried FieldsFunc (No conditional splitting) and Regex (No 'not' operator on go). However, I can do it with complicated loop.

Comment: @Adrian No, I need to escape only /

Comment: @yahavi Try having a look at how the Split method is implemented and use that for inspiration: https://golang.org/src/strings/strings.go?s=7118:7152#L288 Show your attempt and we can suggest changes.

Comment: Please include your current code in your question. Explain its shortcomings and the specific problem you're trying to overcome.

Comment: @Flimzy There is no code to share. I can write the loop and upload it here, but I wanted to find out if go offers me a better way.

Comment: Go offers the same "way" as any other Turing-complete language.

Answer (score 3):

You have two basic approaches available to you, regardless of the language you're using.

1. Search for all occurrences of `/` that are not immediately preceded by `\` and perform a split.
2. Replace all instances of `\/` with some unique symbol that does not contain `/`, then split on `/`, and replace the unique symbol with `\/` again.

From a computational standpoint, the former will be more efficient.

From a coding complexity standpoint, the latter will likely be easier to write.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something in the style of :

```
func split(str string) []string {
    var parts []string
    var current bytes.Buffer
    escaped := false

    for _, r := range str {
        if r == '\\' && !escaped {
            escaped = true
        } else if r == '/' && !escaped {
            parts = append(parts, current.String())
            current.Reset()
        } else {
            escaped = false
            current.WriteRune(r)
        }
    }
    parts = append(parts, current.String())
    return parts
}
```

Go Playground link : https://play.golang.org/p/RwLwFlsAW2Q